# Google Drive Change File Ownership Using RESTapi in Python

Tags: python-2.7, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-python-client

I manage a domain of users and would like to be able to transfer all the documents of a user to another user. As far as I understand the best way to achieve that is to find the fileID's of all files belonging to one user and transfer them to another user. However, I have problem constructing a query.

UPDATE:

So the correct query to retrieve the list of files would be:

```
 response = drive_service.files().list(q="'user@company.com' in owners").execute()
```

However, it only works for me as an admin. If I try to retrieve the list of files for any other user in my domain it returns an empty list.

Answer (score 0):

Files.list will retrieve all the user's files, in this case it will get all your own files. In order for that query to work would be only if that user is also owner one(or more) of your files.

Even as an admin you cannot access users files directly.

To access other user's files, as an admin you need to impersonate the users and then perform actions in their behalf.

This is achieved by using a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) with domain wide delegation of authority.

[Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/delegation) you can find more information on that as well as a python example.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transfer all the files of one user into another user's Drive, the easiest way would be to use the Data Transfer API provided by Google. This way you don't have to list the files and transfer them one by one. Also you only need the admin access token and wouldn't need domain wide delegation either. You can get the official documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/data-transfer/v1/reference/)